# Using python regex to capture one to three words after keyword

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to capture the one to three words after my keyword but some of my cases are not returning all the words. Here are three example strings and the expected output:

- "wait 5h 1m 2s" to ['5h 1m 2s']
- "wait a 5h 1m" to ['5h 1m']
- "wait 1m" to ['1m']

I am trying to use regex because the example strings could be part of a more complicated line. This is my code:

```
In [51]: ex = re.compile('wait (?:A\s)?(\w+\s?\w+?\s?\w+?\s?)', re.IGNORECASE)

In [52]: ex.findall("wait 5h 1m 2s")

Out[52]: ['5h 1m ']

In [53]:ex.findall("wait a 5h 1m")

Out[53]: ['5h 1m']

In [54]: ex.findall("wait 5h")

Out[54]: []
```

Why is the regex not capturing the word after 'wait' and the two optional words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this part:

```
\w+?\s?\w+?
```

The occurrences of `\w+?` are non-greedy, so effectively they mean "take as few word characters as possible (but at least one)". When you put an optional space (`\s?`) between them, what you get is the first `\w+?` matching, for example, `"1"`, skipping the optional space, and then the second `\w+?` matching the `"m"`. So effectively the `1m` is interpreted as two "words".

This would be a good application for the `{}` repetitions notation:

```
>>> ex = re.compile('wait (?:A\s)?((?:\w+\s*){1,3})', re.IGNORECASE)
>>> ex.findall("wait 5h 1m 2s")
['5h 1m 2s']
>>> ex.findall("wait a 5h 1m")
['5h 1m']
>>> ex.findall("wait 5h")
['5h']
```

The `{1,3}` means "match this 1-3 times". And since you're greedily grabbing all the word characters in each go, you can provide the "optional" space as `\s*` to ensure that lack of trailing space won't trip you up.